# d3 Add text element if value exists in data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a library for displaying timelines.  Depending on the data you feed into the library, I want to display elements or not if the data contains a particular value.

Example without `number` value:

```
  var labelColorTestData = [
    {label: "person a", times: [{"color":"green", "label":"Weeee", "starting_time": 1355752800000, "ending_time": 1355759900000}, {"color":"blue", "label":"Weeee", "starting_time": 1355767900000, "ending_time": 1355774400000}]},
    {label: "person b", times: [{"color":"pink", "label":"Weeee", "starting_time": 1355759910000, "ending_time": 1355761900000}, ]},
    {label: "person c", times: [{"color":"yellow", "label":"Weeee", "starting_time": 1355761910000, "ending_time": 1355763910000}]}
  ];
```

Example with `number` value:

```
    var testData = [
            {times:[
                {"id": "day1", "label": "DAY", "number": "1", "starting_time": 1, "ending_time": 86400},
                {"id": "day2", "label": "DAY", "number": "2", "starting_time": 86400, "ending_time": 86400*2},
                {"id": "day3", "label": "DAY", "number": "3", "starting_time": 86400*2, "ending_time": 86400*3},
                {"id": "day4", "label": "DAY", "number": "4", "starting_time": 86400*3, "ending_time": 86400*4},
                {"id": "day5", "label": "DAY", "number": "5", "starting_time": 86400*4, "ending_time": 86400*5}
            ]},
    ];
```

I want to add a text element if the `number` variable exists.  The following code always adds a text element.

```
g.selectAll("svg").data(data).enter()
                        .append("text")
                        .attr("class", "textnumbers")
                        .attr("id", (d) => (d.id))
                        .attr("x", (d, i) => getXTextPos(d, i, d.number, '.textnumbers'))
                        .attr("y", getStackTextPosition)
                        .text(function(d) {
                            return d.number;
                        })
                        .on("click", function(d, i){
                            // when clicking on the label, call the click for the rectangle with the same id
                            var point = d3.mouse(this);
                            var id = this.id;
                            var selectedLabel = d3.select(this).node();
                            var selector = "rect#" + id;
                            var selectedRect = d3.select(selector).node();
                            click(d, index, datum, selectedLabel, selectedRect, xScale.invert(point[0]));
                        })
                    ;
```

How do I add the text element if `number` is present in the starting data and not if it is not?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after `data(data).enter()` paste this line

`.filter(function(d) { return d.number !== undefined; })`